# Reactive function not being found within app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a fairly involved app.  When I call a particular eventReactive function, let's call it function A, within a reactive expression, I get an error that function A cannot be found.

I'm unable to reproduce the exact app because it is proprietary, but I did create a dummy app that simulates the setup I have.  I realize that there must be some difference between the dummy app and what I actually have, but I can't figure it out.  The function in question is there, so I fundamentally don't understand why it's not being found.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
              label = "Choose a number", 
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  actionButton(inputId = "action",
               label = "Update"),
  plotOutput("hist"),
  verbatimTextOutput("stats")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$action, {
    input$num*2
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    data()*2
  })

  output$stats <- renderPrint({
    data2()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Your sample code works fine - every time I press the button, the text on the bottom gets updated to be the input number times 4. There is no plot shown because there is no server code for a plot.

Comment: @DeanAttali, the problem is that in my actual app, which has many features but in which the problem area roughly coincides with the example skeleton I've included, shiny gives me an error on the data function. It says it cannot find the data function when it tries to run the data2 function.

Comment: The problem lies with the way you are calling the two functions. One is a reactive which will run when any change to any reactive variable inside the function occurs, while the `eventReactive` will only run when there is an `input$action`. So what is the point of putting a gate (`input$action`) on the function if you call it immediately with `data2()`? Since there is no input$action, data() is non-existent.

Comment: The logic points out that data2() should be run every time data() runs (w/ `input$action`). So why not put the functionality of data2() under that of data()?

Comment: @Chabo, input$action does exist, as far as I understand.  Thus, when I change the slider and the actiom buttom, it triggers data to run. data2 then runs  and the output is displayed.  If what you're saying is correct, how would we reproduce the error that I'm getting in my actual function in the dummy app ('the function data is not found')?

Comment: I am just generalizing as the above app does not produce an error. What I am trying to get across is maybe some of the gate keeping taking place for your event reactive may be interfering with the function being called by another.  Try ensuring that data() is running by printing to the console when the function runs. If the function is in fact working, and is called when it is supposed to, check to see what you are returning. If you are returning what was expected then the last thing to check is syntax.